# How do I find which PPA to remove from update?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, ppa

When I run apt-get update I get some failures at the end and I'd like to remove them but I don't know which PPA they are coming from. I have Y-PPA Manager installed, but still can't find where it is coming from.

```
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org raring/non-free Translation-en               
Err http://packages.medibuntu.org raring/free amd64 Packages                   
  404  Not Found
Err http://packages.medibuntu.org raring/non-free amd64 Packages               
  404  Not Found
Err http://packages.medibuntu.org raring/free i386 Packages                    
  404  Not Found
Err http://packages.medibuntu.org raring/non-free i386 Packages                
  404  Not Found
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US             
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_US         
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en_US   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_US     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en_US       
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en_US 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en_US   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                        
Fetched 1,302 kB in 17s (73.2 kB/s)                                            
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/raring/free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/raring/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/raring/free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/raring/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the GUI 'Software and Updates' program for that. It's installed by default. Use these instructions

1. Open "Software and Updates" by searching it from the Dash.
2. Open the "Other Software" tab.
3. Find any lines relating to the repository which is giving you problems (Medibuntu in this case) and untick the box in front of it. Note that they may be titled with the full URL or a more friendly name.
4. Close the window
5. Rerun and check if it still errors, if it does, try disabling more related repos.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

Answer (score 2):

All the medibuntu repos aren't working, so this will find where they are

```
grep -RE '^\s*[^#].*medibuntu.*' /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}
```

That will likely just show up a couple of files. Edit those (remove the lines or comment them with a `#`) and your next update should work fine.

Comment: or `sudo sed -i '/medibuntu/d' /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}` ;)